# Fluentd generates empty folders

Tags: json, fluentd, efk

I'm trying to pass an `apache_error` log to fluentd so it can be transformed into a JSON file. But it only generates `file.json` as an empty folder and not as a JSON file.

Here is my `fluentd.conf`:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path E:\Kaggle-datasets\appache-log\apache_error
  pos_file E:\Kaggle-datasets\appache-log\Apache_2k.log.pos
  format apache_error
  tag apache.error
</source>

<filter apache.error>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  reserve_data true
  <parse>
    @type apache_error
  </parse>
</filter>

<match apache.error>
  @type file
  path E:\Kaggle-datasets\appache-log\file.json
  <buffer>
    flush_mode interval
    flush_interval 10s
  </buffer>
</match>
```

Comment: The [`path`](https://docs.fluentd.org/output/file#path) configuration parameter of the `file` output plugin only represents the path up to the directory. The files are generated inside it e.g. the default filename will be `path + time + ".log"`. Also, use [`apache_error`](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/apache_error) in a [`parse`](https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/parse-section) section. As you're using the [`tail` input plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/input/tail), did you verify if there were error logs appended to the input file? If there were no logs then there wouldn't be any files.

Comment: For debugging, you may configure `read_from_head true` for the `tail` and `flush_mode immediate` for the `file`'s buffer section.

Comment: @Azeem ,Hi, thanks for the reply , first if i just specify the path of file output only the directory nothing even it does not even creat that empty folder , second yes there is log file and it's name is apache_error after seeing ur comment i add '.log',for this part "use apache_error in a parse section. As you're using the tail input plugin," i didn't get it , do you mean i should add a parse section in source ?

Comment: Hi! For `tail` to work, there must be new lines being added to the file. If there are no new lines appended to it, there won't be any output. Have you verified that the file is growing but it still doesn't output anything? Also, you might want to test the output with `stdout` output plugin to make sure there's some output. See https://docs.fluentd.org/output/stdout.

Comment: Actually no , there is no news lines added to apache_error.log , the log file have been generated and now i want to analyze , what should change in source to work with static log  ? thanks again for your replies.

Comment: Add `read_from_head true` for `tail` as I mentioned earlier. That'll make it read the file from the start.